# Fluentd and Docker

Tags: regex, docker, fluentd

Hi Guys,

I am redirecting the logs from docker to the stdout in fluentd based on the link : https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/docker-logging

It is redirecting successfully. This is my configuration,

```
<source>
  @type forward
  port 24224
  bind 0.0.0.0
</source>

<filter **>
  @type concat
  key log
  stream_identity_key container_id
  multiline_start_regexp /^error/
  multiline_end_regexp /\s+.*debug$/
</filter>

<match **>
  @type stdout
</match>
```

But my question is,

Multiline configuration is not working, For the below docker log, what is the configuration ( regex ), In my case I need to log multiline 'error' / 'debug' as a single log ?

```
 debug: 2018-04-25T13:28:19.094Z NET_IPC Retry count: 1
       error: 2018-04-25T13:28:19.093Z NET_IPC error Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH 172.30.37.96:6996
               at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
               at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
               at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1182:14)
       debug: 2018-04-25T13:28:19.094Z NET_IPC Retry count: 1
```

Thanks,
Harry

Comment: According to my understanding, you have to use the [multiline parser plugin](https://docs.fluentd.org/v1.0/articles/parser_multiline) in fluentd to join that line.